# Detect SQL Injection

Tags: vb.net, sql-injection, validation

I came to a company that already has a fully grown project... but coders that worked here before me didn't follow conventions and didn't use parametrized SQL queries... as a result there is over 1000 places in a very huge project that can possibly be vulnerable to SQL injection...

I need to find a solution that will automatically detect if there is an SQL injection in the code. So, for example there is a form which allows user to enter comments regarding a product, which will be sent to database on submit... how can we make sure that a user didn't enter a harmfull query instead of a normal text?

Is there any advanced code/regular expression/magic that can detect if this text contains a piece of SQL query instead of normal harmless text? I will accept any links, pieces of code in any language or even commercial software that will do that for me.

Thank you

Comment: What is the project written in?

Comment: The code is written in VB.Net

Comment: If you've got 1000 places where this could be a problem, then it's worthwhile looking for automated ways to edit the code to use parameterized queries.

Comment: Short answer: change them all to prepared statements. Trying to do it any other way is almost certainly going to fail. Also, this is a dupe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx to Detect SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093/regex-to-detect-sql-injection)

Comment: It's not a duplicate (I've looked up that thread before) since I do understand that regular expression will probably not save me and I am looking for a more mature solution... also that thread didn't have an answer that will satisfy me.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but you're looking for failure. "I've got a broken leg and I need to run a marathon tomorrow" is what you're basically telling us. You're going to have to sanitize all of the inputs which means hitting every line of SQL code. If you're there anyway it should be too hard to turn it into a prepared statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no silver bullet here. SQL injections can come in many obscured forms and trying to detect them using regular expressions or another form in your firewall, or application can protect you from the most simple forms of SQL injection, but an experienced hacker will simply get through. As AdaTheDev already noted, automated tools that inspect your code, such as the MS Code Analysis Tool, might give you a kick start, but again there is no silver bullet. You will need to go through your whole application.

When this is a lot of work, you should make a plan. First of all, make a guideline that states how these types of attacks can be mitigated. Also try to divide your application in parts, from very critical to less critical. This way you can better estimate the costs of repairing the bugs and can let management decide what it may cost and thus what risk they are willing to take. Parts of your application that unauthenticated users can access are most critical. If everybody (in the world) can create an account in your application, all functionality that these users can access is highly critical. The smaller the population and the more you trust those users, the smaller the risk. You perhaps can get away with fixing these parts later. But never underestimate a good hacker. He/she might be able to compromise the account of a user with high privilege and start testing for SQL injection possibilities using that account.

Always try to have a defense in depth strategy, have multiple (or many) layers of defence. For instance, do never connect with your database as SA from within your application. Create an account with just the privileges that are needed and perhaps even create multiple SQL accounts, one account per role (or per a group of roles). While restricting the privileges to the database help a lot in mitigating the risk, again, don't bet on it as a single layer of defense. [This article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=44) for instance, explains how a hacker can abuse a lower privilege account when she's able to do SQL injection.

It is admirable that you ask this question here, because I’ve seen many developers in the past who just don’t want to know, which is very scary, because the business often trusts its developers (which is scary as well).

I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

In order to really do this right you need to just divide up the application and go through it one module / page / class / whatever at a time.

This will allow you to not only fix the problem, but also to become much more familiar with the code base in general.

**UPDATE**
Based on the comment I wanted to add one more thing:

The only thing a tool can do is say look, here is some unsanitized inputs... Which, most likely, is going to be just about every query in your app.  Which means you'll have a list of about 3000 or so files that need fixed.

At that point the only thing you can do is designate a day, like Friday, as Fix Sql Day.  Divide up the work and then have everyone spend a day (or even just a couple hours) rewriting the queries on a few pages.

At some point you'll either finish or find enough other things wrong to determine if starting over is a good idea.

Comment: It is a great idea when there is 1-300 files... where as we have over 3000 files, half of them possibly containing badly written SQL... unfortunately it would take over a month to fix all of it... and we don't have so much time in our pocket.

Answer (score 3):

You could give the [MS Code Analysis Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=0178e2ef-9da8-445e-9348-c93f24cc9f9d&displaylang=enInjection.) a whirl which (quote):

> CAT.NET is a binary code analysis tool
>   that helps identify common variants of
>   certain prevailing vulnerabilities
>   that can give rise to common attack
>   vectors such as Cross-Site Scripting
>   (XSS), SQL Injection and XPath
>   Injection.

Never used it myself, but might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I applaud your willingness to dive in and fix things, and not just shrug and say, "ehh.. no one will attack our site anyway".

I think that perhaps the best approach would be to sanitize the inputs, assuming they are innocent, across the board. The problem is, there could be legitimate reasons for someone to enter any of the characters that could trigger SQL Injection.

Just trying to detect such patterns would be subject to false positive 'attack' results; Maybe someone tries to search for `john's car`, not knowing at all that the single-quote could be 'bad'. And maybe they really do need to search for that. Or, what have you...

Comment: I agree. Start looking those windows before installing an alarm!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check wherever variables are passed in to the SQL strings.  For string values, you must you replace every instance of a single quote with a double quote.  For non-string values (those that will pass to the SQL unquoted), you must make sure they are strongly typed.

E.g. don't pass something like `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = " + my_string_user_id`.  Instead, use code `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = " + userId_as_int`.

This worked back in the day when I had a similar codebase with no parameterized queries at all.

Comment: What's even worse is running the SQL access (connection string user) under 'sa'.