# What pattern to check on an SQL query for possible injection?

Tags: sql, mysql, regex, code-injection

I want to detect possible SQL injection atack by checking the SQL query. I am using PDO and prepared statement, so hopefully I am not in the danger of getting attacked by someone. However, what I want to detect is the possibility of input/resulting query string that may become a dangerous query. For example, my app--properly--will never generate "1=1" query, so I may check the generated query string for that, and flag the user/IP producing that query. Same thing with "drop table", but maybe I can check only by looping the input array; or maybe I should just check to the generated query all over again. I am using MySQL, but pattern for other drivers are also appreciated.

I have read [RegEx to Detect SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093/regex-to-detect-sql-injection) and some of the comments are heading in this direction. To my help, I'm developing for users that rarely use English as input, so a simple /drop/ match on the query may be enough to log the user/query for further inspection. Some of the pattern I found while researching SQL injection are:

- semicolon in the middle of sentence -- although this may be common
- double dash/pound sign for commenting the rest of the query
- using quote in the beginning & ending of value
- using hex (my target users have small to low chance for inputting 0x in their  form)
- declare/exec/drop/1=1 (my app should not generate these values)
- html tag (low probability coming from intended user/use case)
- etc.

All of the above are easier to detect by looping the input values before the query string is generated because they haven't been escaped. But how much did I miss? (a lot, I guess) Any other obscure pattern I should check? What about checking the generated query? Any pattern that may emerge?

tl;dr: What pattern to match an SQL query (MySQL) to check for possible injection? I am using PDO with prepared statement and value binding, so the check is for logging/alert purposes.

Comment: Use parameters.  Then you don't need to worry about SQL injection.

Comment: The answer is the same as the one from your link: "Don't do it. You're practically guaranteed to fail. Use PreparedStatement (or its equivalent) instead."

Comment: I'm not too wory about the injection. What I want to know is if any user is *trying* to "inject" the app.

Answer (score 2):

In my shop we have two rules.

1. Always use parameters in SQL queries.
2. If for some reason you can't follow rule one, then every piece of data put into a query must be sanitized, either with `intval()` for integer parameters or an appropriate function to sanitize a string variable according to its application data type. For example, a personal name might be `Jones` or `O'Brien` or `St. John-Smythe` but will never have special characters  other than apostrophe `'`, hyphen `-`, space, or dot`.`  A product number probably contains only letters or numbers. And so forth.

If 2 is too hard follow rule 1.

We inspect code to make sure we're doing these things.

Comment: I follow rule 1. That's not the point, though. What I want to do is to log those who are attempting to do sql injection, so I was thinking to check the input against some known injection pattern so I can mark those users; checkng the input is wee bit too cumbersome as in double loops before sanitizing, while query checking is simpler because I can hook right before/after query execution.

Answer (score 1):

> But how much did I miss?

You guess right. Creating a huge blacklist wouldn't make your code immune. This approach is history. The other questions follow the same idea.

Your best bets are:

- Validating input data (input doesn't necessarily come from an external party)
- Using prepared statements.

Few steps but bulletproof.

Comment: I'm not trying to blacklist query. I want to know if there's any of the user is trying to.

Comment: That's called blacklisting.

Comment: I was thinking blacklisting would make the app reject the query. Anyway, the query, especially the _description_-like text input will not reject the user's input, but I want the app to log the user writing that kind of input. And, yes, all inputs use prepared statements and parameter binding for the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

You will spend the rest of your life in an armament race -- you build a defense, they build a better weapon, then you build a defense against that, etc, etc.

- It is probably possible to write a 'simple' `SELECT` that will take 24 hours to run.
- Unless you lock down the tables, they can look, for example, at the encrypted passwords and re-attack with a `root` login.
- If you allow any type of string, it will be a challenge to handle the various combinations of quoting.
- There are nasty things that can be done with semi-valid utf8 strings.
- And what about `SET` statements.
- And `LOAD DATA`.
- And Stored procs.

Instead, decide on the minimal set of queries you allow, then parameterize that so you can check, or escape, the pieces individually.  Then *build* the query.